# Javascript Code Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript Code

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#write");
button.addEventListener("click", write);
var field = document.querySelector("#field").value;

function write() {
  alert(field);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<input type="text" name="field" id="field">
<button type="button" id="write">Write</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Why this code doesn't show anything?
If i change this code

```
var button = document.querySelector("#write");
button.addEventListener("click",write);
var field = document.querySelector("#field");
function write(){
  alert(field.value);
}
```

Now the string is displayed on the screen

Comment: You need to move `var field = document.querySelector("#field").value;` to the function -  the value is gotten at load time and that is too early for your function

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: You set the variable `field` before any text is in the box. You need to get the new value after some text has been entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the first code snippet

```
var field = document.querySelector("#field").value; // (1)
function write(){
  alert(field);
}
```

You are getting value at `(1)` before you call `write` which will either contain nothing or just undefined. While on the 2nd snippet:

```
var field = document.querySelector("#field"); // (1)
function write(){
  alert(field.value);
}
```

You just explicitly reference `field` first on `(1)` and then retrieve the value when you call `write()`.